# Hex String to Image File from varbinary(max)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, file

I have a table in a database which stores image files in varbinary(max) type. I would like to extract, convert and save the image file. Then, I used the cast as varcharmax to extract:

```
cast([IMG_FILE] as varchar(max))
```

The result of this cast looks like a hex string (I've removed part of string to protect the privacy of the person):

```
\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
```

I tried to used this hex string in a online tool (https://codepen.io/abdhass/full/jdRNdj), and the image is corrected displayed (remembering that I've cutted part of string to preserve the persons privacy):

[image]

Then, I've tried to take this hex string and tried to convert to a image file using python3. I've been trying a lot of things (the majority found here), but until now, I coudn't save the correct file.

1. Saving directly doesn't generate the image.

   with open(photo_path + 'file.jpg', 'wb') as new_jpg:
   new_jpg.write(hexString)
2. Using binascii.unhexlify returns **"Non-hexadecimal digit found"**

   binascii.unhexlify(hexString)
3. Converting to int/bin returns  **invalid literal for int() with base 16**:

   bin(int(hexString, 16))[2:]

I would like to know how to solve this problem? That is, I would like to take this hex string and save a image file in my computer.

Comment: you can't use it as a string. You would have to convert every two chars to integer value - ie `int(hexString[0:2], 16)` - to create bytes array and then you can save it in file. Can't you get it as bytes from database ?

Comment: I've tried to get it as bytes from database but doesn't work, it looks like that python gets the b' of hex string. For instance, if I try to take directly the bin and print it, appears: b'\\xffd8ffe000104a46494600010100000100010000fffe003b43524541544f523a2067642d6a7065672076312e302 ......

Comment: do you keep it in database as raw data (only pixels) or JPG, PNG (compressed data with headers) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have string without `\x` then I can convert every two chars to integer value, create `bytearray` and save it

```
text = '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'

integers = []

while text:
    value = int(text[:2], 16)
    integers.append(value)
    text = text[2:]

data = bytearray(integers)    
    
with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    print(fh.write(data))
```

If I have string with `\x` then first `\xff` is treated as char's code so I have to use `ord()` to convert it integer.

```
text = '\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'

integers = []

value = ord(text[0])
integers.append(value)
text = text[1:]

while text:
    value = int(text[:2], 16)
    integers.append(value)
    text = text[2:]

data = bytearray(integers)    
    
with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    print(fh.write(data))
```

Because string in your question is incomplete so it creates incomplete image.

But with data from link it create correct JPG file.

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you have raw string and `\x` is treated as normal string, not part of byte `\xff` -  and you have to remove `\x` at start using using `text = text[2:]`

```
text = r'\xffd8ff...'

integers = []

text = text[2:]

while text:
    value = int(text[:2], 16)
    integers.append(value)
    text = text[2:]

data = bytearray(integers)    
    
with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    print(fh.write(data))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Simpler version with standard module `codecs`. It still need to remove `\x` from string.

If you have bytes:

```
text = b'\\xffd8ff...'  # bytes

import codecs

text = text[2:]         # remove `\x`

data = codecs.decode(text, 'hex_codec')

with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(data)
```

If you have string - then you have to first `encode()` to bytes:

```
text = '\\xffd8ff...'   # string

import codecs

text = text.encode()    # bytes
text = text[2:]         # remove `\x`

data = codecs.decode(text, 'hex_codec')

with open('output-1.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(data)
```

Comment: Your code worked, but I've tried to execute getting from  database and I having this error:  value = int(text[:2], 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'xf'

Comment: it seems database treats `\x` as normal string so you would have to use `text = text[2:]` at start to remove it - without using `ord()`

Comment: BTW: what do you get if you don't use CAST ? Maybe you get it as bytes and then you could save it without all this conversion.

Comment: Unfortatelly I'm not able to change the query, I would have to ask to data analyst why he can't use CAST like you suggested.

Comment: I add in answer simpler version using standard module `codecs`